# Instagram Real-Time

Tags: real-time, instagram, subscription

I have a doubt about real-time Instagram subscription in the API. Can i subscribe to whatever user i want? or there is some restrictions about the users that i want to subscribe?

I arises this doubt because in the Instagram of real time subscriptions page says: Note that this subscription is for all of the client's authenticated users, not just a specific user.

Its means that i can only subscribe the users that have authorithed my app in Instagram??
I have to make an app that consumes the instagram subscriptions and when there is a new photo it automatly saves it in the DB.
Thanks

Comment: I figured it out it only subscribes to users who has authorised the app so i cant do what i want.

Answer (score 0):

A few things, first if you use the "user" type, then you are correct it will ping your endpoint any time any user who has authorized your app posts, there is no IG side filter (yet), but you can easily filter on your end once you get the notification.  Oddly, I did notice it now sends the media_id of the post (although the docs say it doesn't!?).  If users do not authorize your app, then the only way to get notifications is via the other endpoints such as by tag.

I have found some issues though when dealing with "private" users, and some strange filter behavior to watch out for.

A final point, you said you want to save to your db - that could be in violation of their use policy, so be sure to clearly understand what IG's rules are and that you don't break them.

Hope this helps,
P